# Extracting a zip file from another directory, it copies the name of the zip file e.g App1.zip but i just need App1 no zip

Tags: c#, zip

I have extracted a zip file called `App1`, when I extract it the folder name becomes `App1.zip`. Is there any way I can remove the `.zip` from the new folder name?

I have tried

```
File.Replace(OutputFolder, ".zip", " ");
```

Code:

```
if (extension == ".zip")
{
    if (CreateFolderForZipFile == true)
    {
        ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(path, path.Replace(InputFolder, OutputFolder));
    }  // if
    else if (CreateFolderForZipFile == false)
    {
        ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(path, Path.GetDirectoryName(path.Replace(InputFolder, OutputFolder)));
    }  // elseif
```

This creates a folder that isn't a zip but is called `App1.zip`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(path, Path.GetDirectoryName(path.Replace(InputFolder, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(OutputFolder))));
```

Or just do

```
OutputFolder = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(OutputFolder);
```

before the original line if you can modify the contents of OutputFolder.

EDIT:
If you are really desperate you can try changing line 4 to this:

```
ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(path, path.Replace(InputFolder, OutputFolder).Replace(".zip","");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but unfortunately these didnt work :(

Comment: @Nicola I'm surprised. Can you debug the code and copy the contents of "OutputFolder" before the extract here?

Comment: OutputFolder "C:\\DECC\\Output" string
But the return is this                                                   string.Replace returned "Output\\1\\2\\App1.zip" I want to remove the .zip

Comment: also with your code im putting stuff in my visual studio project debug folder?

Comment: @Nicola Change the inputfolder instead then. The second argument of the ExtractToDirectory method is what contains the ".zip". If you are really desperate you can try: ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(path, path.Replace(InputFolder, OutputFolder).Replace(".zip","");

Comment: OMG thanks so much, ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(path, path.Replace(InputFolder, OutputFolder).Replace(".zip","")) worked for me. I changed to ".zip" to extension so it looks better. Thanks so much for all your help!

Comment: @Nicola no problem! If you want you can accept the answer with the green tick at the left of it. Have a nice day =).